# Как изменить папку загрузки с Git?

Tags: git

Мне нужно поменять папку загрузки на компьютере, как это можно сделать?Извините за возможно глупый вопрос)

Comment: Что за папка загрузки? При чём тут git?

Comment: папка в которую я с помощью гит качаю обновления с гитхаба

Comment: Ну перенесите её в другое место

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию файлы репозитория и метаданные репозитория хранятся в одной папке. Метаданные хранятся в скрытой подпапке `.git`. Поэтому, чтобы продолжить полноценную работу с репозиторием, нужно папку в новое место перенести целиком.

---

Кому интересно, то задать раздельное хранение можно через параметр `--git-dir`